# Treasure hunt for edges

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to make a children's treasure hunt where the next location is given by a picture e.g.
[image: Play hut]

To make a more suitable printable picture, I can use `-canny` like this:

```
convert hut.jpg -canny 0x1+10%+30% -negate hutCanny.jpg
```

[image: Hut drawn with lines]

To make it more interesting, I was thinking that I want to make *two images* -one with horizontal lines and one with vertical lines:

```
convert hut.jpg -colorspace gray -morphology Convolve Sobel -negate hutH.jpg   
convert hut.jpg -colorspace gray -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 -negate hutV.jpg
```

[image: Hut with horizontal lines]
[image: Hut with vertical lines]

I would like the location to be only guessable when both picture are found and can be *combined using a light source*. The problem is that `Sobel` not only detects vertical lines but also angled lines. As can be seen, the location is far too easy to recognise with just one picture. I have been trying with different kernels and trying to erode the pictures. -nothing woks.

---

How do I make two images that by themselves are not 'guessable' but can be combined to one. e.g. by making one image with *only* near horizontal lines and an other with *only* near vertical lines?

Comment: What is the location in the picture?

Comment: The example picture is an unknown location from google search. The real picture has many of the same features - a hut in a forrest.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following in ImageMagick. Make a random mask and apply it to the image. Then invert the mask and do the same. The two images, when added together, will make the input.

Input:

[image]

```
convert \( hut.png -write mpr:img +delete \) \
\( mpr:img +noise random -channel g -separate +channel -blur 0x5 -threshold 50% +write mpr:mask +delete \) \
\( mpr:img mpr:mask -compose multiply -composite +write hut_out1.png \) \
\( mpr:img \( mpr:mask -negate \) -compose multiply -composite +write hut_out2.png \) \
null:
```

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2:

[image]

**ADDITION**

If it has to be grayscale, then you can do the above and make each output gray.

```
convert \( hut.png -write mpr:img +delete \) \
\( mpr:img +noise random -channel g -separate +channel -blur 0x5 -threshold 50% +write mpr:mask +delete \) \
\( mpr:img mpr:mask -compose multiply -composite -colorspace gray +write hut_out1.png \) \
\( mpr:img \( mpr:mask -negate \) -compose multiply -composite -colorspace gray +write hut_out2.png \) \
null:
```

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2:

[image]

Now add them together to reconstitute:

```
convert hut_out1.png hut_out2.png -evaluate-sequence add hut_out12.png
```

[image]

Comment: A very good idea, but I can not make it work with `-canny` or `-charcoal` to make a printable version.

Comment: Why do you need edges or such? Must it be printed black/white?

Comment: Yes - I only have a black/white printer